# Does the following characterization of subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ generalise?

Tags: algebraic-groups, matrices, reference-request

Let $p$ be a prime number. By a **Cartan subgroup** of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ I mean an absolutely semisimple maximal abelian subgroup.

When $n=2$, it is well-known* that, for $G \subset GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of order prime to $p$, either $G$ is contained in a Cartan subgroup, or it is contained in the normalizer of a Cartan subgroup, or its image in $PGL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is isomorphic to $A_4$, $A_5$, or $S_4$.

> I would like to know if there is a similar result for larger even values of $n$;

where a subgroup of order prime to $p$ would either be contained in the normaliser of a Cartan, or its projective image be one in a finite list of groups.

*See e.g. section 2 of Serre's "Propriétés galoisiennes..." paper.

Comment: Presumably we should read "A_4, A_5, or S_4" as "a finite subgroup of PGL_2(\mathbb  C)".

Comment: @Will: Actually no, I really do mean in $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Now you might ask for which $p$ this is possible. Restricting to odd $p$, $A_4$ and $S_4$ always embed in $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, and $A_5$ embeds if and only if $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod 5. 

Comment: @Will: Your comment is in the right direction, though it omits the cyclic groups.   This comment does reinforce my sense that higher values of `$n$` will get arbitrarily hard for list-making.

Comment: @Barinder: I don't understand your definition of "Cartan subgroup", since Serre is considering both the split and non-split maximal tori in a finite group of Lie type (not just the split tori). Aside from that, I doubt very much that anything as simple as the case `$n=2$` will occur for larger `$n$`. The subgroup structure rapidly gets much more complicated. 

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for your comment. But does my definition of Cartan subgroup really force me into the split case? I didn't think that it did.

Comment: @Berinder: I guess the unfamiliar terminology "absolutely semisimple" is throwing me off.   This is not a typical way to define "Cartan subgroup" in any area of Lie theory.  Also, it seems like overkill to
write "is contained in a Cartan subgroup, or is contained in the normalizer of a Cartan subgroup".    But my main concern is that for large `$n$` and various primes `$p$` you may find too many sorts of finite groups of order prime to `$p$` embedded in general linear groups. 

Comment: @Jim: Of course, the cyclic groups embed in $PGL_2(\mathbb F_p)$, as do dihedral groups, which I think are almost the only normalizers of Cartan subgroups that appear. The other ones also live in $PGL_2(\mathbb C)$.

In fact, I have an official wild guess: every subgroup of $PGL_n(\mathbb F_p)$ is the image of some subgroup of $PGL_n(\mathcal O)$, where $\mathcal O$ is the ring of integers of a number field where $p$ splits completely.

Comment: Argument: Consider the algebraic variety whose coordinates are the elements of the matrices that generate your group, and whose equations are derived from the relations. This variety has a point over $\mathbb F_p$. Now unless we can derive the equation $N=0$ for some $N$ a multiple of $p$, from the defining equations, this thing will have a point in characteristic $0$. The only place such an equation could reasonably come from is requiring that a unipotent matrix have order $p$, and that's impossible because $p$ does not divide the order of the group. Or something like that.

Comment: I have no reason to be talking about $PGL_n$ instead of $GL_n$.

Comment: @Will: Thanks for your interesting thoughts, especially about this variety. It does make me feel that one first needs a characterisation over $\mathbb{C}$ (or any alg closed field) before tackling my stated question; and Jim's comments suggest to me that this is probably not possible. 

Comment: @Barinder: After some thought I think that a proof can probably come out of considering the rings $\mathbb Z[G]$ and $\mathbb F_p[G]$ for $G$ the group in question.

I agree with your guess on a general classification being impossible. It seems to work in two dimensions because $SU_2$ is just a double cover of $SO(3)$, which has a nice finite subgroup classification theorem.